# Consuming WEB API REST GET Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a WEB API hosted on a server, there I have a Products table with Name and Description.I already checked for the postman and this is ok, when I try to implement the method in xamarin by visual studio to bring a record by its name and display in a listview I can not. Could someone help me in the code

```
private async void GetProductByName(string Name)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {

            txtTest.Text = "http://www.ProdutosAPITest6.hostname.com/api/products";

            var URI = txtTest.Text + "/" + Name.ToString();

            var response = await client.GetAsync(URI);

            string products = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            var product = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Produto>(products);

            listview.ItemsSource = products;

        }
    }



    <ListView x:Name="ProductsList" ItemSelected="listaProducts_ItemSelected" 
       BackgroundColor="Aqua" SeparatorColor="Blue">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>

                        <StackLayout Padding="10,10" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Id}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="Blue" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Description}" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: What is going wrong?

Comment: I dont know the listview does not return any records

Comment: Are you getting results back from the server? Please show your `Produto` model and `ListView`

Comment: public class Product
    {
     
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

Comment: And the `ListView`? It might be better for readability to add them to your question

Comment: everything works on postman the records are returning

Comment: Yes but this is not Postman. Did you debug and verify that `products` has records?

Comment: yes everithing is ok on postman

Comment: I think there is some error in the code but I do not know what it is

Comment: Why are you using `listview.ItemsSource = products;` and not `ProductsList.ItemsSource = products;`?

Comment: sorry I'm using ProductsList.ItemsSource but it does not work

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on `listview.ItemsSource = products;` and inspect what is inside the `products` variable. Is there something in there?

Comment: How and where is `GetProductByName` being invoked. The `async void` means it is not happening on the UI thread so the UI is unaware of any updates.

Comment: listview.ItemsSource = products;  products is a raw string, where product is the deserialized json.  But you are only deserializing a single json object, not an array.  There are MANY, MANY things wrong this code as posted.  Use the debugger to step through the code and verify each line is doing what you expect.

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code? Have you check Json is Desalinizing Properly or not? ItemSource contains value or not?

Answer (score 0):

I made a little edit to your code.

```
public async void GetProductByName(string Name)
    {
                var handler = new NativeMessageHandler();
                var client = new HttpClient(handler);
                client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120);

                txtTest.Text = "http://www.ProdutosAPITest6.hostname.com/api/products";
                var URI = txtTest.Text + "/" + Name.ToString();

                var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage
                {
                    Method = HttpMethod.Get,
                    RequestUri = new Uri(URI)
                };

                var response = await client.SendAsync(requestMessage);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode == true)
                {
                    var products = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    var resultModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Produto>(products);
                    return resultModel;
                }
    }

public ListView myListView { get { return ProductsList; } }

protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
                var name = //pass name;
                List<ProductModel> products = await GetProductByName(name);

                if (products.Count() > 0)
                { 
                     myListView.ItemsSource = products;
                }

           base.OnAppearing();
   }
```

I hope this helps